# Неясность с запятой между "поэтому" и "благодаря"

Tags: пунктуация

"Поэтому(,)благодаря примечательной внешности, дяде Васе был открыт быстрый и беспрепятственный вход в любые лаборатории и машинные залы." 

Вроде бы без запятой тут не обойтись! Но разные источники советуют ставить или не ставить запятую по-разному. Даже в Нацкорпусе встречаются разные варианты с этим же деепричастным оборотом - http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%CF%EE%FD%F2%EE%EC%F3+%E1%EB%E0%E3%EE%E4%E0%F0%FF+

Comment: Как видите, в Нацкорпусе нашлось только 3 вхождения, причем то вхождение, где *поэтому* стоит в начале предложения — не Ваш случай. Вам бы следовало показать предыдущее предложение, ведь Ваше предложение фактически является его продолжением.

Comment: Пожалуйста:"Если честно, теперь Василий Семёнович с большим удовольствием сбрил бы это, с таким трудом заработанное украшение, чтобы не сильно выделяться в толпе. 
Но, во-первых, он в любой толпе всё равно выделялся, благодаря росту и телосложению. А во-вторых, даже если кто из сотрудников Станции не слишком хорошо знал инженера по коммуникациям в лицо, то про единственного человека на Станции, носящего шевелюру, был осведомлён точно. 
Поэтому благодаря примечательной внешности, дяде Васе был открыт быстрый и беспрепятственный вход в любые лаборатории и машинные залы."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В **Полном академическом справочнике "Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации"** говорится следующее:

Обороты с производными предлогами и предложными сочетаниями **обязательно** обособляются, если они располагаются между подлежащим и сказуемым: разрыв их непосредственной связи и способствует выделению оборотов. В других позициях такие обороты могут не обособляться (без необходимости подчеркивания).

Ср.: **Благодаря дождям посевы зазеленели. — Посевы, благодаря дождям, зазеленели.**

См. также на **Грамоте.**

**Однако возможны и иные варианты пунктуационного оформления, обусловленные замыслом автора.**

> Например: На следующее утро **благодаря** многочисленным пришельцам в четверть часа остов новой землянки был закончен (В. Обручев, Земля Санникова) – **невыделение оборота, находящегося не в начале и не в конце предложения.**

**В спорных случаях окончательное решение о постановке знаков препинания принимает автор текста.**

Comment: Хорошие у нас правила! :) "Строго запрещено, но если хочется, то можно". Спасибо. Поставлю запятую. Так как-то лучше выглядит.

Comment: Запрещено? Запятая ставится в обязательном порядке между подлежащим и сказуемым, В остальных случаях факультатива.

Comment: Ну, в моём случае - факультатива. :)

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы!

Answer (score 1):

ПоЭтому, **благодаря примечательной внЕшности,** дяде Васе был открыт быстрый и беспрепятственный вход в любые лаборатории и машинные залы.

Обособление обстоятельственных оборотов с производными предлогами факультативно и зависит от структуры предложения и распространенности оборота. Оборот должен или вписаться в интонационную структуру предложения, или должен обособляться.

В нашем случае оборот в эту структур не вписывается, что видно по расстановке ударений.

Comment: В принципе, я и проверяю тексты на "чтении вслух". Как бы я сам начитывал. И эта фраза прямо просит поставить запятую. :)

Comment: Вы правы. При чтении текст делится на фразы, которые обозначаются паузами и тоническими ударениями. В данном случае прочитать это предложение как простое неосложненное просто невозможно. Мы ставим  ударение на первом наречии, а поле ударения обязательно следует пауза. Еще одно ударение делается на обособленном обороте.  Авторское (факультативное) обособление - это же не авторский произвол,  а выбор обоснованного решения для конкретного предложения

Answer (score 0):

Построение типа "вход открыт благодаря внешности" надо признать неудачным (у входа нет внешности), поэтому я перестроил предложение.

**Поэтому благодаря примечательной внешности дядя Вася получил быстрый и беспрепятственный доступ в любые лаборатории и машинные залы.**

Оборот *благодаря примечательной внешности* не является ни деепричастным , ни  пояснительным, поэтому не нуждается в выделении запятыми.

**Поэтому благодаря примечательной внешности дяди Васи, ему был открыт быстрый  и беспрепятственный доступ в любые лаборатории и машинные залы.**

Оборот отделен запятой в силу своей распространенности.

**Поэтому примечательная внешность дяди Васи давала (обеспечивала) ему быстрый и беспрепятственный доступ в любые лаборатории и машинные залы.**

Если писать проще, то:

**Поэтому благодаря своей примечательной внешности дядя Вася мог беспрепятственно входить в любые лаборатории и машинные залы.**

Comment: В данном тексте слово "получил" не отражает сути предложения. См. выше более полный текст.

Comment: Насчёт остальных вариантов надо подумать. Но в контексте фраза (на мой взгляд) смотрится органично. От слова "доступ" веет казёнщиной. Но может быть я и не прав.

Comment: От слова "доступ" веет казёнщиной - согласен, но быстрый вход - звучит странновато.

Comment: Если писать проще, то:  Поэтому благодаря своей примечательной внешности дядя Вася мог беспрепятственно  входить в любые лаборатории и машинные залы.

Comment: В моё время это никого не удивляло, если честно. :) Но я - человек старорежимный. Да и слог произведения выбрал из шестидесятых-семидесятых. Надо соответствовать, тем более, что пишу околонаучную чушку.  :)